# Invoke every HttpRequest after login in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Increasing User Threads in my JMeter performance testing, found some of the requests called before login. So those requests were failed.

### My Test plan is below

[image]

In .csv file, added 1000 users with `{email, password}` and given to `Login Http Request -> CSV Data Set Config`. I'm extracting `{uid}` from login response and stored in `uid`

Second Random Controller, have multiple HttpRequest's, every request needs `{uid}`.

This works on below 50 user threads. But when i increased threads, some Random Controller ==> Http Request sends without `uid`

See, this one is with `uid`
[image]

But this one is with out `uid`

[image]

Can any one help me, how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 possible reasons:

1. Your application gets overloaded therefore your `Login Request` doesn't return correct `uid` so your extractors fail
2. Your JMeter intsance get overloaded so JMeter cannot handle 50+ users as you are running it in a non-optimal way

I would start with point 1 by temporarily enabling storing requests and responses data into .jtl results file by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

This way you will be able to see response data for failed requests using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and will be able to identify where the test fails.

Other things worth checking/implementing:

- check your application logs
- setup monitoring of baseline OS health metrics (CPU, RAM, Disk/Network IO) on both JMeter and application under test sides, you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](http://How%20to%20Monitor%20Your%20Server%20Health%20&%20Performance%20During%20a%20JMeter%20Load%20Test) for this
- Make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), i.e.

  - Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode
  - Increase JVM heap size
  - Switch to JSR223 Test elements instead of Beanshell

Comment: Thanks for your analysis and suggestions. I'll try with your suggestions